# Cannot create alias with ampersand in bash

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

New to bash/linux: I have seen other questions but none of the answers seem to help, I would like have an alias that does 3 things:

1. Opens the folder with my project.
2. Starts up my code editor (webstorm)
3. Starts up my server

I was able to do 1 & 3 but with 2 I have an issue since the ampersand is causing issues.
Here is the alias:

```
# alias for opening and running AdminApp
  alias aa='cd Desktop/code/AdminApp && webstorm . /& && nodemon --exec npm 
  start'
```

This works fine:

```
alias aa='cd Desktop/code/AdminApp && nodemon --exec npm
```

As you can see I am using the `/` , also tried with the `$` at the beginning of the command to escape either way I get this message:

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `&&'
```

If I remove the ampersand then it will open the editor but not move on to the next command.

Comment: What are you tryign to do with `webstorm . /&`? Why are you using aliases? Just use functions

Comment: @Inian I am trying to do what I wrote in 2, startup my code editor. 
There are no variables here, why would I need a function?

Comment: @Michael aliases are not for compound commands

Comment: @oguz would a function be the correct approach?

Comment: @Michael: Can you try `alias aa='cd Desktop/code/AdminApp && webstorm . & ; nodemon --exec npm start'`. You don't need to escape `&` and also you can run a background command in combination (using &&) with another command

Comment: @Inian I get this when running that command:
"
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
"

Comment: Maybe `alias aa=' { cd Desktop/code/AdminApp && webstorm . & }; nodemon --exec npm start'`

Comment: unfortunately gives me this:
`bash: syntax error near unexpected token `&&'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple: `&` already delimits a [command](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Lists.html#Lists), and another delimiter (`&&`, `;` etc.) immediately following is wrong. Just write (regardless whether as a direct command or within `alias aa='…'`):

```
cd Desktop/code/AdminApp && (webstorm .& nodemon --exec npm start)
```

Comment: this does not run the server on the correct file. I think that the '/' escapes the previous string. 
I get the webstorm ide to run but then the `nodemon...` command does not, tells me:
`bash: .: /: is a directory`

Comment: @Michael - Ah, I corrected my error. Besides, '/' doesn't escape anything, you confuse it with '\'. And there is no lone '/' in my answer.

Comment: I marked your answer correct since this helped and worked, I am still getting this message from the terminal:
`bash: .: filename argument required
.: usage: . filename [arguments]
`
What does it mean?

Comment: @Michael - Did you use the exact command above, or a variation of it, and if the latter, which exactly?

Comment: @Michael - I am puzzled. Does one of the three commands `cd Desktop/code/AdminApp`, `webstorm .` and `nodemon --exec npm start` give that error if entered alone?

Comment: @Michael - And how is it if you omit the `.`? (I'll be offline now for 16 hours.)